# Porque el erros, soy nuevo solo estoy haciendo un programa que me cuentes las veces que se repite una letra en un texto

Tags: python

```
def leer_frase():
    global txt 
    txt=(input("Ingresar un Texto ")).lower()
    
    def contar_letra_ingresadas():
        letra = (input("Ingrese la letra que busca: ")).lower()
        contar = 0 
        for i in txt:
             if(i.isalpha()):
               if(letra==i):
                  contar+=1
        print("La letra: ",letra,"se repite",contar,"veces")
                
leer_frase()
contar_letra_ingresadas()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso pasa por que la funcion que queres ejecutar se almacena en una variable local de la funcion "leer_frase", que solo es accesible dentro de la funcion "leer_frase" y existe solo durante la ejecucion de esta. Lectura recomendada: https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/

Answer (score 2):

El error es definir una función dentro de otra. Si bien es válido y tiene uso, lo que se define dentro de una función, sólo se conoce dentro de ella; deja de existir cuando la función retorna.

Normalmente las funciones se declaran a primer nivel, así:

```
def leer_frase():
    global txt
    txt = (input("Ingresar un Texto ")).lower()

def contar_letra_ingresadas():
        letra = (input("Ingrese la letra que busca: ")).lower()
        contar = 0
        for i in txt:
            if (i.isalpha()):
                if (letra == i):
                    contar += 1
        print("La letra: ", letra, "se repite", contar, "veces")
```

Eso soluciona tu problema.